# Output PHP into a Variable for JSON

Tags: php, json

```
file1.php
<?php
$listMenu=array('Menu #1','Menu #2','Menu #3');
?>

<div class="wjNavButton"><a><?php echo($listMenu[0]); ?></a></div>
<div class="wjNavButton"><a><?php echo($listMenu[1]); ?></a></div>
<div class="wjNavButton"><a><?php echo($listMenu[2]); ?></a></div>


file2.php
$buff=include('file1.php');
$rest='[{sectionId:"LT", sectionType:"menu", sectionData="'.$buff.'"}]';
echo($rest);

result:
[{sectionId:"LT", sectionType:"menu", sectionData="1"}]

question:
- is this possible to put result of php page in variable?
- how i can result as output of file1.php and not sectionData="1"?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ob_start();
include 'file1.php';
$buff = ob_get_clean();

$data = array(array('sectionId' => 'LT', 'sectionType' => 'menu', 'sectionData' => $buff));
echo json_encode($data);
```

- You can't get the contents of a page using `$buff = include`. Imagine `include` as copy and pasting the contents of one file into another. It doesn't return anything. (Unless you structure your include files differently so it does, read [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php).)
- You can capture and get the content using [output buffering](http://www.php.net/ob_start) though.
- Never write your own JSON, use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to make sure your syntax is correct and values are escaped properly.

Comment: thank for JSON advice, when I try to execute that code I get: [{"sectionId":"LT","sectionType":"menu","sectionData":"\n\n\n\n   why I get that, is something wrong?

Comment: @comenk What do you mean? The `\n\n\n`? Those are the line breaks in your `file1.php`. Try [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) if you don't want them.

Comment: Thank's alot.. now I can get what I want

Comment: @GregSchoen + deceze : I'm glad have u guy's in stackoverflow. and I'm sorry for my english. I come from Indonesia.

Answer (score 1):

file2.php

```
$buff=include('file1.php');
$rest='[{sectionId:"LT", sectionType:"menu", sectionData="'.$buff.'"}]';
echo($rest);
```

Looks like you needed a closing quote on that string.

Comment: thanks GregSchoen, but what I'm realy wan to ask it how to put result of file1.php in my variable

Comment: see deceze's answer, I would upvote it more if it were allowed. :)